# Create URL based on values from model

Tags: python, django

I want to create a blog page and it works perfectly but I want to change the URL for the specific blog post. Currently the URL to the specific blog post is **myurl.com/blog/pk** , but I want it to be **myurl.com/blog/category/title** instead. How can I do this? Also appreciate any kind of critique to the code, if you feel like it.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, null = True, blank = True)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='posts')

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from .models import Comment
from .forms import CommentForm
from django.http import HttpResponse


def blog_index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_on')
    context = {
        "posts": posts,
    }
    return render(request, "blog_index.html", context)


def blog_category(request, category):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        categories__name__contains=category
    ).order_by(
        '-created_on'
    )
    if not posts:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    context = {
        "category": category,
        "posts": posts
    }
    return render(request, "blog_category.html", context)


def blog_detail(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)

    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = Comment(
                author=form.cleaned_data["author"],
                body=form.cleaned_data["body"],
                post=post
            )
            comment.save()

    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    context = {
        "post": post,
        "comments": comments,
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "blog_detail.html", context)
```

**App urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.blog_index, name="blog_index"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.blog_detail, name="blog_detail"),
    path("<category>/", views.blog_category, name="blog_category"),
]
```

**Project URL**

```
path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```

Comment: You can not use a title, or at least that is not recommended since a title can contain spaces, punctuations, etc. typically one uses a *slug* for that.

Comment: That makes sense. Would it cause any issues changing my Model field from `Charfield` to `slug` ? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: typically you add a `slug` field for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite convinced that you do *not* want to use a title. Titles can usually contain spaces (), punctuations (`~!#.?`, etc.), and special characters. A URL can not contain most of these characters. One can indeed escape these characters, but then the URL looks quite ugly like:

```
myurl.com/some%20title%20containing%20spaces
```

Now that is not very readable.

You can however use a *slug*, with a [**`SlugField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield). A `SlugField` is a `CharField`, but it does some cleaning to avoid ugly URLs. For example `'some title containing spaces'` will be converted to `some-title-containing-spaces`.

You can add a `SlugField` to your `CategoryModel` like:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the `urlpatterns` we can specify a `slug` as:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blog_index, name='blog_index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.blog_detail, name='blog_detail'),
    path('category/<slug:category_slug>/', views.blog_category, name='blog_category'),
]
```

We can then filter in our view on the slug:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404
from .models import Post

def blog_category(request, category_slug):
    posts = get_list_or_404(Post.objects.filter(
        categories__slug=category_slug
    ).order_by(
        '-created_on'
    ))

    context = {
        'category': category,
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog_category.html', context)
```

## Generating unique slugs

It might sometimes happen that the `slug` already exists for another `Category` object, we can use a script to generate a unique slug, for example:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
from itertools import count

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i in count():
            slug = slugify('{}{}'.format(self.title, i or ''))
            if not Category.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
                break
        self.slug = slug
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Running `migrate` gives me the following error - `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__blog_category.slug` 

Also isn't `blog_detail()` the one deciding the URL to the specific blog post and not the `blog_category()` ? Currently `blog_category()` creates a page with all posts under that category which I want. I just want the final url for the clicked blog post to be named `MyUrl.com/blog/category/title`

Comment: @LesnieSncheider: the fact that the migration fails is because you add an extra field `slug`, and now that field is not unique across the records. In case you want the slug on the `Blog`, you should indeed add it to the `Blog` model.

Comment: I deleted the `slug` from the `Category` model and it still causes the same issue now.

Comment: @LesnieSncheider: yes, that is because it is still in a migration file, you should remove that one too.